# Tar not excluding directories?

Tags: linux, tar

I just have tried to exclude couple of directories while creating a tar archive. 
The directory structure is rather simple (Centos 6, tar v1.23):

```
/test/t1
     /t2
     /t3
     ...
```

each subdirectory (t1, t2, t3, ...) contains some txt files. Nothing unusual.

Fine, lets try this:

```
tar czvf test.tar.gz test/ --exclude={"t2"}
```

Failed, `t2` subdirectory is included in the archive.

```
tar czvf test.tar.gz test/ --exclude={"t2",""}
```

Success, `t2` is excluded - as expected.

I have tried to reproduce the same situation on my laptop (Ubuntu18.04, tar v1.29) with the same directory structure. Here, the both commands failed - the `t2` directory was included in the created archive!

1. Why a single directory entry, provided in `{}` is not working?
2. Why are the results different in different environments?

What is going on here? Is this something about the tar version? Linux distro dependent? Looking at the tar manual (current, v1.32) nor the tar changelog gave me any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from the end.

> Why are the results different in different environments?

In some versions of `tar` `--exclude=…` counts only for paths (e.g. `test/`) that come after it. This means `tar … test/ --exclude=t2` works as if there was no `--exclude` at all. GNU `tar` 1.29 in my Debian 9 behaves like this for sure.

You claim in 1.23 `--exclude` after a path works (at least in some circumstances). I have no reason not to believe you. In fact I reached GNU `tar` 1.26 in Debian 7 and it behaves like you described for 1.23.

Conclusion: place `--exclude=…` before paths like `test/`.

---

> Why a single directory entry, provided in `{}` is not working?

This one is not about `tar`, it's about the shell and brace expansion the shell performs (or not). Not all shells do it. [Bash does](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html), so does Zsh. Plain POSIX shell doesn't have such functionality.

In a shell that supports brace expansion invoke:

```
printf '<%s> ' --exclude={"t2"}; echo
printf '<%s> ' --exclude={"t2",""}; echo
printf '<%s> ' --exclude={foo,bar,"baz qux"}; echo
```

In each output whatever is inside `<>` is a separate argument `printf` got. You will see respectively:

```
<--exclude={t2}>
<--exclude=t2> <--exclude=>
<--exclude=foo> <--exclude=bar> <--exclude=baz qux>
```

I used `<>` to be able to tell for sure there may be multiple arguments rather than a single argument with spaces.

You may have thought `--exclude={foo,bar,baz}` makes `{foo,bar,baz}` get to `tar` and the tool interprets it as some kind of list. No. The shell expands this syntax and generates *multiple* words before `tar` is started. The tool gets these words as command line arguments, interprets them as options and is not aware there were some braces involved; exactly like `printf` got its arguments.

And now the quirk: for brace expansion to occur, there must be at least one comma (`,`) or dot-dot (`..`, it serves different purpose) inside the braces. From the linked manual for Bash:

> A correctly-formed brace expansion must contain unquoted opening and closing braces, and at least one unquoted comma or a valid sequence expression. Any incorrectly formed brace expansion is left unchanged.

We may call `--exclude={"t2"}` an incorrectly-formed brace expansion. The string is left unchanged, `tar` gets it almost as it was typed (almost, because [quotes are removed](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quote-Removal.html)). The tool would exclude a file literally named `{t2}`. As you can see there is no reason to exclude `t2` then; `t2` is not `{t2}`.

On the other hand `--exclude={"t2",""}` is a correctly-formed brace expansion and it expands to `--exclude=t2` `--exclude=`. The latter excludes nothing but `tar` doesn't complain. The former excludes `t2` as you wanted.

`--exclude={foo,bar,baz,whatever}` saves you typing `--exclude=` again and again thanks to the feature of the shell. But in the end `tar` will get

```
--exclude=foo --exclude=bar --exclude=baz --exclude=whatever
```

as if you typed four `--exclude=` statements.

If there is just `foo` to exclude then you must not shorten the "list" to `--exclude={foo}`, it should be just `--exclude=foo`. You discovered you can use `--exclude={foo,}` but this is quite cumbersome and serves no purpose. Remember these braces are not required by `tar`, they never get to it.

Note if you ever want to exclude any file ([of any type](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690), including files of the type directory) *literally* named `{foo,bar,baz,whatever}` then you need to quote to prevent brace expansion from kicking in:

```
--exclude='{foo,bar,baz,whatever}'
```

Comment: Hmm? "...  if you ever want to exclude **a single** file literally named {foo,bar,baz,whatever}"

Comment: @Hannu I don't get the point of your comment. `{foo,bar,baz,whatever}` is a legitimate name for a file. Why "single"?

Comment: You have this one quoted: `--exclude='{foo,bar,baz,whatever}'` in a way that indicates a single file, still the text says 'files' i.e. plural, more than one. Confusion?

Comment: @Hannu This will exclude *any* file literally named `{foo,bar,baz,whatever}` regardless on directory the file is in. There may be at most one such file per directory. There may be *many* directories in the tree being archived. Therefore "files".

Comment: Ahh... same filename but in any dirs, didn't think of that. Maybe you can add THAT to the text; e.g. "note: may exist in more than position in the directory tree"

Comment: @Hannu This aspect of `--exclude=` is not the issue here, I find it tangential. If there's any doubt, a separate question should address it. Still I admit the word "files" might be misleading in the context of "the shell expanding braces and generating multiple words", as if such expansion occurred here as well. I'm changing "files" to "any file".

Comment: exclude before path worked for me in bash 5.1.16 on ubuntu 22.04