# Speeding up find command result with folder exclusions

Tags: command-line, unix, find

I have the following folder structure:

```
Approvals_Share
    1 CUST APPROVAL
    2 LICENSE APPROVAL
    CANADA INSCRIBE
    z-remove
```

There are multiple subfolders and illustrator files “.ai” inside each folder

If I perform a `find` individually on each folder I get the results back in the amount of time specified below between square brackets:

```
1 CUST APPROVAL: [14m 19s]
2 LICENSE APPROVAL: [10m 17s]
CANADA INSCRIBE: [13s]
z-remove: [2s]
```

Here is a sample shell command that I use to lists the `z-remove` folder

```
cd '/Volumes/Box/Approvals_Share/z-remove/'
find .  -name '*.ai' -not -name '.*' > output.txt
```

This task takes only 2 seconds to complete, however if I run the same command on the parent folder `Approvals_Share` excluding all folders except `z-remove` the task takes 3m 27s. I was expecting it to be 2s or way closer. Here is the shell command I’m using:

```
cd '/Volumes/Box/Approvals_Share/'
find .  -name '*.ai' -not -name '.*' -not -path './2 LICENSE APPROVAL/*' -not -path './1 CUST APPROVAL/*' -not -path './CANADA INSCRIBE/*' > output.txt
```

Is there a way to speed up the result?

Answer (score 1):

Using `not -path` requires traversing all the excluded directories with ignoring the output, reason why it's taking more time.

The solution here consists of using `-prune`, it forbids `find` to access to the children of every pattern within `-path` option:

```
cd /Volumes/Box/Approvals_Share/
find . -path './2 LICENSE APPROVAL' -prune -o -path './1 CUST APPROVAL' -prune -o -path './CANADA INSCRIBE' -prune -o -name '*.ai' -not -name '.*' -print
```

Another way consists of grouping the excluded directories :

```
find . -type d \( -path './2 LICENSE APPROVAL' -o -path './1 CUST APPROVAL' -o -path './CANADA INSCRIBE' \) -prune -o -name '*.ai' -not -name '.*' -print
```

Comment: This is the right approach since the excluded folders are really the known thing here. Eventually, there could be new folders like `z-remove` that will need to be scanned and listed as well. Unfortunately, there is something off with your script, it started listing the content of the excluded folders.

Comment: Where are you executing the command from, because i have already tested this method and it's working you should execute it on the parent directory : cd /Volumes/Box/Approvals_Share/

Comment: Yes, from Approvals_Share of course. I'm generating the shell commands programmatically but I'm checking at the string before running it and it matches yours, no double spaces, etc. Do you have a bunch of ai files inside your test folders?

Comment: Yes in each folder and in subfolders, i have made an edit to try the same in another way.

Comment: The grouped version you posted also lists the content of the excluded paths.

Comment: Have you edited something on this command or just copy past because the order is important ?

Answer (score 0):

[This other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1532104/432690) is right but it requires you to explicitly specify all directories you want to exclude. The solution doesn't scale up well. What if there are hundreds of directories in `.`?

Your requirement is to exclude all directories except `z-remove` (and `.` implicitly in the first place, otherwise it wouldn't make sense). A more scalable solution should specify `z-remove` (and `.`) only, as this information is enough to exclude the rest.

If you know there are no matching files directly in `.` then all of them (if any at all) will be in `z-remove`. In such case use this straightforward approach:

```
find z-remove -name '*.ai' ! -name '.*'
```

<sup>(Note: I used `!` because it's POSIX while `-not` is not.)</sup>

If there can be matching files directly in `.` then you need to start in `.` (obviously) and prune every directory that is not `.` or `./z-remove` or inside `./z-remove`. Like this:

```
find . -type d ! -path . ! -path ./z-remove ! -path './z-remove/*' -prune \
       -o -name '*.ai' ! -name '.*' -print
```

Note your original code does not use `-type f`, so e.g. a directory `./z-remove/foo.ai` will pass all the tests. You're talking about files and in Unix [directory is also a file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690). But you're talking about "illustrator files", so maybe you mean regular files and `-type f` is what you want. If so, my solution becomes:

```
find . -type d ! -path . ! -path ./z-remove ! -path './z-remove/*' -prune \
       -o -type f -name '*.ai' ! -name '.*' -print
```