# what is the right approach to count the open files

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, lsof, file-descriptors

what is the real way to verify open files

what we do is that

```
lsof  | sort | uniq >/tmp/file
```

so `/tmp/file` include all open files

and the number of open files can be identified by

```
wc -l /tmp/file
3259806 /tmp/file
```

until now cool

but when we are looking at that file we saw

```
more /tmp/file

abrt-dbus 189428                  root    1u     unix 0xffff883fcd70c380       0t0      61987 socket
abrt-dbus 189428                  root    2u     unix 0xffff883fcd70c380       0t0      61987 socket
abrt-dbus 189428                  root    3u  a_inode                0,9         0       7411 [eventfd]
abrt-dbus 189428                  root    4u     unix 0xffff883da772cb00       0t0 3903424237 socket
abrt-dbus 189428                  root    5u  a_inode                0,9         0       7411 [eventfd]
abrt-dbus 189428                  root  mem       REG              253,0    110808  201609749 /usr/lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
abrt-dbus 189428                  root  mem       REG              253,0   1141560  201609729 /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
abrt-dbus 189428                  root  mem       REG              253,0    118672  202713390 /usr/lib64/libpolkit-gobject-1.so.0.0.0
abrt-dbus 189428                  root  mem       REG              253,0   1257792  203905333 /usr/lib64/libnss3.so
abrt-dbus 189428                  root  mem       REG              253,0   1287904  201610325 /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.4200.2
abrt-dbus 189428                  root  mem       REG              253,0    142304  201609747 /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
abrt-dbus 189428                  root  mem       REG              253,0    147096  201609950 /usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1
```

so do the following lines also need to be considered as open files? or not?

```
abrt-dbus 189428                  root    1u     unix 0xffff883fcd70c380       0t0      61987 socket
abrt-dbus 189428                  root    2u     unix 0xffff883fcd70c380       0t0      61987 socket
abrt-dbus 189428                  root    3u  a_inode                0,9         0       7411 [eventfd]
abrt-dbus 189428                  root    4u     unix 0xffff883da772cb00       0t0 3903424237 socket
abrt-dbus 189428                  root    5u  a_inode                0,9         0       7411
```

or

we need to count only the lines that ended with files as

```
abrt-dbus 189428                  root  mem       REG              253,0    110808  201609749 /usr/lib64/libresolv-2.17.so
abrt-dbus 189428                  root  mem       REG              253,0   1141560  201609729 /usr/lib64/libm-2.17.so
abrt-dbus 189428                  root  mem       REG              253,0    118672  202713390 /usr/lib64/libpolkit-gobject-1.so.0.0.0
abrt-dbus 189428                  root  mem       REG              253,0   1257792  203905333 /usr/lib64/libnss3.so
abrt-dbus 189428                  root  mem       REG              253,0   1287904  201610325 /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0.4200.2
abrt-dbus 189428                  root  mem       REG              253,0    142304  201609747 /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
abrt-dbus 189428                  root  mem       REG              253,0    147096  201609950 /usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1
```

Comment: I think all of them they are [files](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690).

Comment: ARE YOU SURE!!!!!!!!!

Comment: how this line - abrt-dbus 189428                  root    1u     unix 0xffff883fcd70c380       0t0      61987 socket    , IS A FILE?

Comment: Socket is a file of type socket. See this: [Everything is a file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file). Do you want to count *regular* files maybe?

Comment: my question is because we reached the max open file , so I want to know what is the right approach to fined the open files

Comment: You should [edit] and move the above comment to the question body. Compare [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107576/discussion-between-king-david-and-kamil-maciorowski).