# How can I get the output of `du -c` without the word `total`?

Tags: grep, du

I want to get the total size of a directory and all directories inside it.

I am using the command

```
du -h -c "$input_variable" | grep total
```

It prints the results and the word `total`. How do I get the results without the word `total`?

Answer (score 8):

You're passing exactly one [file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690): `"$input_variable"`, so you can get rid of `grep` by using `-s` instead of `-c`:

> `-s`
>   Instead of the default output, report only the total sum for each of the specified files.

<sup>([source](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/du.html))</sup>

If I'm reading the documentation right, `du` should use a space character in its output to separate size from pathname. Common implementations use tab though. `awk` with its default field separator should be able to separate the first field in both cases:

```
du -hs "$input_variable" | awk '{print $1}'
```

Notes:

- the solution does not rely on the word `total`, so localized `du` may also be supported;
- `-s` is a portable option, while `-c` is not (and `-h` you used is not portable either).

Comment: Thanks for the command it worked. One question when I use get info on the dir it has diffrent file size then the Du command. Why would that be

Comment: @user1555314 What do you mean by `get info on the dir`?

Comment: @user1555314 Probably because of this: [Why are there so many different ways to measure disk usage?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120311/108618)

Answer (score 3):

With GNU du:

```
du -sh "$input_variable" | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: You beat me to it. I decided to post my answer anyway because it contains links and some explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Pipe it into `sed`: `| sed 's/\ttotal//g'`

Comment: Would this be how you write the command du -h -c dir | grep total | sed 's/\ttotal//g'

Comment: @user1555314 Try it and find out.