# Dovecot: Relative home directory paths not supported

Tags: linux, links, dovecot, roundcube

I got a problem with dovecot, I have an external disk with all the emails in the Maildir format, I mounted this disk in Linux and for each user, I created a symbolic link (with ln -s) and then i started Dovecot with roundcube, when i go to see Dovecot log it says that he doesent support relative home directory paths. I tried to copy the folder without making a link, but nothing changed.
Can please someone help.
Thanks

Comment: Do the links use relative paths? What if you used absolute paths?

Comment: I cant use an absolute path because they can point  only at a file, not at a directory, so I can't use them

Comment: I don't understand. [Directory is also a file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690). Did you mean "regular file"? By definition [absolute path starts with `/`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_02) and [relative path doesn't](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_324). One kind or the other can point to any type of file or even to a nonexistent path.

Comment: Now I *suspect* maybe you thought about [hardlinks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22394/108618).

Comment: Yes maybe is like you say, how can I create an absolute path, just for check if I did it right.

Comment: What is the exact `ln -s …` command you used?