# My Tar backup has the wrong permissions

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, tar

I'm on Debian Sid, using GNU tar and I want to make a backup of a system directory

```
root@debian:/usr# ( cd /usr ; tar cf - ./share ) | ( cd /home ; tar xf - )
```

but *some* of the directories extracted into `/home` have different permissions, e.g.,

```
$ ls -ld /{home,usr}/share/{wallpapers,xindy}
drwx------ 4 root root 4096 Oct  1 00:22 /home/share/wallpapers/
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 May 16  2016 /home/share/xindy/
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Sep 30 19:45 /usr/share/wallpapers/
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4096 May 16  2016 /usr/share/xindy/
$
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: I just noted that there is also a difference re the dates of modification…

Comment: @TelamonAegisthus The original permissions are already reported in my question, aren't they?

Comment: Is the command still running?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes, it's still running, do you mean that…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unexpected permissions and date of `/home/share/wallpapers/` are because the command is still running.

Imagine `tar` is used by an ordinary user to extract a directory (owned by the user) with `r-xr-xr-x` permissions and some files within. If `tar` applied these permissions before extracting the files, it couldn't proceed with the files. To deal with this the tool grants itself write access first (`rwxr-xr-x`), restores the files, only then it changes the permissions to exactly what they should be.

`tar` extracting as root does it somewhat differently. It creates directories initially belonging to `root:root` without any access rights for group or other. Only after it processes all the files within, it sets ownership and permissions as they should be. This means temporarily even the ownership may not match. In your case the original directory is owned by `root:root`, so incidentally the ownership matches. Still you're observing the temporary user-only permissions.

Similarly, restoring timestamps too early makes no sense. Changes within the directory would affect them.

In any case the point is `tar` needs to delay restoring some metadata until it "thinks" it's done with the directory.

How can `tar` know this? Well, it cannot know for sure. Your extracting `tar` reads from a non-seekable pipe and it absolutely cannot know what paths it will get in the future. Even while reading from a seekable file `tar` would read it sequentially.

What happens is the tool assumes that after encountering `share/wallpapers/` all the directory content immediately follows. In other words: after `share/wallpapers/` there are zero or more [files](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690) with paths starting with `share/wallpapers/`. Then a path not starting with `share/wallpapers/` indicates we're done with `wallpapers` and the metadata of the directory can be finally restored. This approach works fine with archives created by a single `tar` processing a single starting point (like in your case), because the creating `tar` does process files in the expected order.

Archives created by more than one `tar` (e.g. think about `--append`) or when multiple files were specified in arbitrary order may contain members in unusual order. In this case the following option is useful while extracting:

> `--delay-directory-restore`
> Delay setting modification times and permissions of extracted directories  until  the end of extraction. Use this option when extracting from an archive which has unusual member ordering.

So it delays restoring metadata even more.

If your extracting `tar` used this option, you would observe unexpected permissions for `/home/share/xindy/` and `/home/share/wallpapers/` at the same time. You didn't use the option and apparently the observation was made after the extracting `tar` assumed it's done with `xindy`, therefore for this directory you observed the right permissions. At the time of the observation `tar` was not yet done with `wallpapers` though.

Wait until the command finishes. All the permissions should then be right.