# How does exec interact with pipes in shells?

Tags: bash, shell

Assume I have the following in the beginning of my code:

```
exec < file
```

It means, if I understand correctly, that all commands trying to read from stdin will actually read from `file`.

But if I have `cmd1 | cmd2`, will `cmd2` read from the `cmd1`'s output or `file`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It means, if I understand correctly, that all commands trying to read from stdin will actually read from file

A command reading from its stdin will read from a regular file if *its* stdin happens to be a regular file. A command reading from its stdin will read from a terminal or fifo (which are also [files](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690)) if *its* stdin happens to be a terminal or fifo respectively.

Stdin of one command can be different than stdin of another command.

In a script interpreted by `bash`, `exec < file` redirects the stdin of this particular `bash` process only. Later commands will be affected if they inherit stdin, but the inheritance happens in the same way regardless if you used `exec < file` or not.

If you run just `cmd0` then it will inherit stdin and stdout (and stderr) from the interpreting `bash`. It's irrelevant what the stdin and stdout of the interpreting `bash` are; the mechanism is always the same.

If you run `cmd1 | cmd2 | … | cmdN` then `cmd1` will inherit stdin from the interpreting `bash` and `cmdN` will inherit stdout from the interpreting `bash`. Other stdins and stdouts will form a pipeline (stdout of `cmd1` connected to stdin of `cmd2` and so on). It's irrelevant what the stdin and stdout of the interpreting `bash` are; the mechanism is always the same.

The fact you used `exec < file` is irrelevant to the mechanism itself. Some command(s) will inherit stdin and/or stdout from the interpreting `bash`. Without `exec < file` they would inherit *something*. With `exec < file` they will inherit *something else* as stdin.

This means `exec < file` can affect some commands, but only commands that inherit stdin from the interpreting `bash`. Your `cmd1` does inherit the stdin of the interpreting `bash`, but `cmd2` does not.

Assuming your `cmd2` simply reads from its stdin, it will read from the output of `cmd1`. The prior `exec < file` doesn't matter. (Note in general `cmd2` may redirect or ignore or close its stdin; commands designed to work in pipelines don't do this, unless told to.)

You can test this in a script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Don't run this in an interactive shell. Run as a script.
exec < /etc/fstab
echo foo | cat
wc -l
```

Note if you paste the above code in an interactive `bash` then you will change the stdin of the `bash` itself and it will eventually exit upon EOF. For your convenience below is a version that can be run in an interactive shell without terminating it:

```bsh
bash -c '
   exec < /etc/fstab
   echo foo | cat
   wc -l
'
```

The output should be `foo` (proving `cat` reads the output of `echo`) followed by a number being the number of lines in your `fstab` (proving `wc` reads from `fstab`).