# Why can't I open a directory that I have been working on as a directory in Linux anymore?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm SSH'ing into a machine to complete some work. In my home directory, I previously had a subdirectory, let's call it `myDirectory` which I could move to from within the `home` directory using `cd` as with any other directory (i.e. `cd ./myDirectory`).

Now, when I run the command, I get the error:

> "myDirectory not a directory"

and when I run `ls` the `myDirectory` is color-coded differently than other directories, and differently than it had been previously. I *can* however, run `mv someFile ./myDirectory`, and recently moved a number of files (which I now need to access) in this way.

So, `myDirectory` obviously points to a directory, but is not at `~/myDirectory` any longer. I believe I understand the problem, however I'm not sure what command to use to access the directory. How can I access this directory and/or determine its new location?

Running this command:

```
ls -ld myDirectory
```

Produces:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 myUsername myUsername 15029 Nov  2 17:57 myDirectory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `-` in the output of `ls -ld myDirectory` indicates `myDirectory` is a [regular file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/183999/108618), not a directory.

I can only speculate how this happened. One possibility is you (or someone/something) renamed/moved/deleted the original directory `myDirectory`, so no entry named `myDirectory` was there; then you renamed some regular file `someFile` to `myDirectory`.

`mv someFile ./myDirectory` renames `someFile` to `myDirectory`. The old regular file named `myDirectory` (if existed) is lost. This means if you renamed more than one file this way, only the last one can be easily recovered; it's under the name `myDirectory`.

To avoid such mishaps add a trailing slash when you refer to what you think is a directory. If you did

```
mv someFile ./myDirectory/
```

and `./myDirectory` was not a directory, the tool would complain without moving anything.

Up to this point we assumed `someFile` is a regular file. If it could be of the type directory ([which is also a file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690)) then (depending of what you want to do) [it might be even better to append `/.`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/606385/108618) instead of `/`.