# Do sticky bits in Linux permissions make a difference if a group owns the directory

Tags: permissions

Here is the question.

> "Suppose in CentOS, there is a directory "/project", owned by group
> "IT". Both user "peter" and "stewie" belond to the group "IT".
>
> If system administrator would like to set permission on this directory
> "/project", to support the function "the files created by peter cannot
> be deleted by stewie". Which command or file permission should be
> set?"

Sticky bit is the correct answer, however definitions for sticky bit are:

> When a directory's sticky bit is set, the filesystem treats the files
> in such directories in a special way so only the file's owner, the
> directory's owner, or root user can rename or delete the file.

With directory owner being the main point here.

Since both users are part of the group "IT" which owns the "/projects" directory, why does sticky bit still work here? Peter is in fact unable to delete any files made by Stewie and vice versa despite both being part of a group that owns the directory. Is this a definition error or my misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevant POSIX definitions:

> [File Owner Class](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_174)
>
> The property of a file indicating access permissions for a process related to the user identification of a process. A process is in the file owner class of a file if the effective user ID of the process matches the user ID of the file.

> [File Group Class](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_167)
>
> The property of a file indicating access permissions for a process related to the group identification of a process. A process is in the file group class of a file if the process is not in the file owner class and if the effective group ID or one of the supplementary group IDs of the process matches the group ID associated with the file. […]

Note the classes are named "File Owner" and "File Group". There is no "owner" in the latter term. **Where you see "file owner" (or "file's owner", like in the definition you cited) it's all about the user, noting about the group.**

Yet another POSIX definition confirms this interpretation:

> [File Permission Bits](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_175)
>
> Information about a file that is used, along with other information, to determine whether a process has read, write, or execute/search permission to a file. The bits are divided into three parts: **owner, group, and other**. Each part is used with the corresponding file class of processes. These bits are contained in the file mode.
>
> […]

<sup>[Emphasis mine]</sup>

It says "owner, group, and other" where we could informally say "user, group, and other".

People who say  'File owner… You mean the user owning the file? or the group?'  are not fully POSIX-compliant.

The definition for sticky bit uses the term "file's owner", it doesn't use the term "file's group" (or "file group"). This means it has nothing to do with groups, groups are irrelevant to how the sticky bit works.

The answer to your question

> why does sticky bit still work here?

is: because it doesn't take groups into consideration *at all*.

> Is this a definition error or my misunderstanding?

The definition is consistent with this behavior because it refers to "file owner", not once to "file group". There is no definition error.

---

To be clear what the cited question is about.

Without the sticky bit set for the directory, without [ACL](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/acl.5.html) for the directory, this is how its permissions work:

- Are the user in question the one that owns the directory?

  - Yes → The owner's permissions matter. Nothing else matters. End procedure.
  - No → Are the user in question in the group that owns the directory?

    - Yes → The group's permissions matter. Nothing else matters. End procedure.
    - No → The other's permissions matter. End procedure.

Common permissions for a directory are `rwxrwxr-x` where the second `rwx` is the group's permissions. `w` in it indicates any user in the right group can add files to or remove files from the directory (almost, because for the owner the first `w` matters, not the second; if it were `r-xrwxr-x` the actual owner could do less than other members of the right group, even if the owner was in the group).

When the cited question reads

> there is a directory `/project`, owned by group `IT`. Both user `peter` and `stewie` belong to the group `IT`

it's to indicate both `peter` and `stewie` can probably delete any file in the directory, including the other user's files. The task is to change it so

> the files created by `peter` cannot be deleted by `stewie`

Before setting the sticky bit the "file group" for the directory ([which is also a file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690)) matters when it comes to deleting a file from the directory. After setting the sticky bit the situation changes. The definition says "only the file's owner, the directory's owner, or root user can […] delete". The dependence on the "file group" no longer holds.

Comment: Joke: Many people have an illegal space character in their name, so they cannot be fully POSIX-compliant anyway. This includes me. Sigh…