# Moreutils' Chronic reports everything in STDOUT, but only when run in cron

Tags: linux, debian, cron, stdout, stderr

I prepared the following script to test chronic & cron:

```
echo "normal out"
echo "error out" >&2
exit 0
```

When I run it on normal shell with `chronic -ev`, output is as expected:

```
$ chronic -ev /path/to/test.sh 
STDOUT:
normal out

STDERR:
error out

RETVAL: 0
```

So I added it to my crontab like this

```
MAILTO="me@mycompany.com"
* * * * * chronic -ev /path/to/test.sh
```

And I get email (configured with postfix) like this:

```
STDOUT:
normal out
error out

STDERR:

RETVAL: 0
```

So two surprising things happen:

- When run by cron, all output seems to be redirected to STDOUT
- Chornic's `-e` flag "fires" anyway, so it must detect something that appeared on STDERR.

Info about the system:

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
$ chronic --version
/usr/bin/chronic version [unknown] calling Getopt::Std::getopts (version 1.12 [paranoid]),
running under Perl version 5.28.1.
```

Is it possible that it's a bug in chronic or crontab? Or I don't understand something fundamental about how output is handled in cronjobs?

PS: I also tried:

- `* * * * * cd /path/to; chronic -ev ./test.sh`
- `* * * * * /usr/bin/chronic -ev /path/to/test.sh`
  All with the same result

Answer (score 1):

#### Analysis

Without involving cron you can replicate the problem by comparing the output of the following commands in a shell:

```sh
chronic -ev /path/to/test.sh              # chronic printing to tty
chronic -ev /path/to/test.sh 2>&1 | cat   # chronic printing to non-tty
```

Now compare the output of these two:

```sh
chronic -ev /path/to/test.sh  >/dev/null   # suppressed stdout
chronic -ev /path/to/test.sh 2>/dev/null   # suppressed stderr
```

You will find that only `error out` is printed to stderr. Everything else *including* `STDERR:` is printed to stdout.

There is [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476089/108618) that elaborates on output buffering when the [stdio library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_file_input/output) is involved. In my Debian 10 the output of `chronic --version` is exactly like in the question. `chronic` is `/usr/bin/chronic` which is a Perl script with `/usr/bin/perl` in the shebang. Then `/usr/bin/perl` is an ELF executable and `ldd` tells me it requires `libc.so.6`. Libc is the ["standard C library"](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages//man7/libc.7.html). This information may not be enough to be sure the stdio is involved; but even if it's not, in the context of this question `chronic` behaves as if it was. In the worst case the linked answer provides useful context.

Let's assume stdout and stderr are the same file (note: terminal (tty) is also a [file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690)). From the linked answer we can extract this:

- By default stderr is unbuffered, written immediately.
- By default stdout is

  - fully buffered if it's a non-tty,
  - line-buffered if it's a tty.

And

> Programs can reprogram each file to behave differently, and can explicitly flush the buffer. The buffer is flushed automatically when a program closes the file or exits normally.

`/usr/bin/chronic` in my Debian contains this relevant code:

```perl
sub showout {
        print "STDOUT:\n" if $opt_v;
        print STDOUT $out;
        STDOUT->flush();
        print "\nSTDERR:\n" if $opt_v;
        print STDERR $err;
        STDERR->flush();
        print "\nRETVAL: ".($ret >> 8)."\n" if $opt_v;
}
```

I don't know Perl *at all*, but the code seems quite simple. Knowing in advance what is printed to where helps. This is what happens at some point:

- `STDOUT->flush();` flushes the buffer of stdout,
- then `\nSTDERR:\n` is printed *to stdout*,
- then something (e.g. our `error out`) is printed to stderr,
- finally `STDERR->flush();` flushes the buffer of stderr.

If everything goes to a tty, line-buffered `STDERR:` is printed immediately because there's also a newline character (`\n`) at the end. Then unbuffered `error out` is printed immediately and everything is in sequence.

If everything goes to a non-tty, fully buffered `STDERR:` is placed in the newly flushed buffer (not printed immediately), but unbuffered `error out` is printed immediately and therefore it appears before `STDERR:`.

Even if Perl does not rely on stdio or if it changes something in the default behavior so the above description is not fully accurate, stderr is explicitly flushed so it behaves as unbuffered, while the buffering of stdout clearly depends on whether it's a tty or not.

I think you have discovered a bug.

---

#### Your options

- Wait for `chronic` in Debian to get patched.
- Patch your `/usr/bin/chronic` and risk that possibly unpatched new version will bring the bug back in the future.
- Patch and use a copy of `/usr/bin/chronic`, but then you may miss a patched and *otherwise improved* new version in the future.
- Provide a tty for unpatched `chronic`.
- <strike>Change buffering with `stdbuf`.</strike>

  I tried to use `stdbuf -e0 -o0 chronic …` to no avail. Perhaps Perl behaves like Python (see [*Why `stdbuf` has no effect on Python?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55655236/10765659)). `stdbuf` is *not* an option.

Whatever you choose, you may or may not report the bug.

---

#### The patch

You can patch `chronic` or its copy by swapping two lines of code. Change this snippet:

```perl
STDOUT->flush();
print "\nSTDERR:\n" if $opt_v;
print STDERR $err;
```

to this:

```perl
print "\nSTDERR:\n" if $opt_v;
STDOUT->flush();
print STDERR $err;
```

The patched code flushes the buffer of stdout directly before printing something to stderr. Now there is no way `STDERR:` appears too late.

---

#### Providing a tty

Use `unbuffer` (from the `expect` package in Debian) to provide a tty for (possibly unpatched) `chronic`:

```
unbuffer chronic …
```

Note an outermost tool (like cron) that is about to run some command (e.g. `chronic …`) may redirect stdout and stderr of the command to different [files](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690), then it can tell apart the two streams. This is if fact what `chronic` itself does to your script or whatever. But if you tell the tool to run `unbuffer chronic …` instead then `unbuffer` will redirect stdout and stderr of `chronic` to *the same* pseudo-tty. The two streams will merge into one, it will be printed by `unbuffer` to its stdout. The outermost tool can still redirect stdout and stderr *of `unbuffer`* to different files, but this will not unmerge the two original streams. It seems with cron this is not a problem because it merges all the output anyway.

With `chronic` `unbuffer` works, `stdbuf` doesn't. This is because [they work in completely different ways](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97327/108618).