# Recursive symlink gets created when using ln -f -s

Tags: unix, symbolic-link

if I create a folder inside my current folder, say logs:-

```
mkdir log
ln -s -f log all_logs
```

such that all_logs points to the log directory.

```
ls -ltr
Jan  7 23:33 log
Jan  7 23:33 all_logs -> log
```

When i run `ln -s -f log all_logs` again, a recursive symlink gets created *inside* the log directory, named log.

```
ls -ltr log/
Jan  7 23:33 log -> log
```

Why does this happen ? Shouldnt the existing symlink only get unlinked and relinked ( with the -f option) ? Why is this recursive behaviour occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Shouldnt the existing symlink only get unlinked and relinked

Nope. The command is resolving the existing link as a directory target, `log/.`

Symlinks aren't files. For example:

```
# touch test
# mkdir testdir
# ln -s -f testdir test
# ls -l
Jan  7 11:28  test -> testdir
```

If the link target is an already existing *file*, it will be overwritten by the `-f` option of `ln`.

If you want to override this behavior on GNU `ln`, use the `-T` option to `ln`, which is "treat LINK_NAME as a normal file always".

If on BSD `ln`, use `-h`, which is "If the target_file or target_dir is a symbolic link,    do not follow it."

Comment: But isnt the -f option used to overwrite the existing symlink ? What can i do to make the same command be used for both new symlinks and for existing ones ?

Comment: symlinks aren't files. If the file being overwritten is a normal file, -f will do what you expect. If it is an already existing symlink, that symlink gets traversed, and you wind up with a link inside your target directory. I updated my answer.

Comment: my version of unix doesnt have -T as an option. 
ln [-Ffhinsv] source_file [target_file]
These are the only options

Comment: In that case, use the `h` option. You're on the bsd version of `ln`. `-h` is "If the target_file or target_dir is a symbolic link, do not follow it."

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot !

Comment: "Symlinks aren't files." – By what definition? [POSIX explicitly states that "symbolic link" is a type of file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690).

Comment: I should have said *regular* files. This is a distinction made by various userspace tools, where symlinks and directories receive special treatment, despite being technically file entries.

Answer (score 1):

Extract from the manual (it is the same for `mv` and `cp`, though they don't have the 2nd form).

```
SYNOPSIS
       ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME
       ln [OPTION]... TARGET
       ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY
       ln [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY TARGET...
```

Note that the 1st form and the 3rd form (when given 2 arguments), are ambiguous.
Therefore to avoid ambiguity: when writing to a directory use the 4th form, and/or append `/` to the directory name. When using the 1st form (because one is not specifying a directory), use the `-T` option. Unfortunately this is not available to all, so bugs will happen (thinks will do the unexpected). It this situation `-h` can be used on BSD, or `-n` that dose the same, but works on BSD and GNU.