# Use pdfinfo on multiple PDFs then extract filename and number of pages

Tags: linux, pdf, find

I have directories (and subdirectories) with several thousand PDFs and was trying to get the total pages in all those PDFs together. So I try running this command:

```
find . -name \*.pdf -exec pdfinfo {} \; | grep Pages > filelist
```

And I get the number of pages for each file piped into the `filelist` file.

I would really like to also have the filename piped in but can't figure out how to do it (`pdfinfo` returns a lot of data about the PDF but not the filename itself).

Answer (score 0):

Precede `-exec` with `-print`. This way the pathname will be printed by `find` before the respective `pdfinfo` prints its output. `-print` is the default action (e.g. when you run sole `find .`), but the presence of `-exec` suppresses the default.

If you prefer the pathname after the output of the respective `pdfinfo` then you may try `-exec … -print`, but note in this case `-print` will be performed iff `-exec` (i.e. `pdfinfo`) succeeds.  In general one uses `-exec … -print` when `-exec` is used as a test. In the context of your question I personally prefer the pathname first, so `-print -exec …`.

Then you need to adjust your `grep`. Use the fact every pathname considered by `find .` must start with `.`. `grep -E '^(\.|Pages)'` matches lines with a literal dot at the beginning or the string `Pages` at the beginning.

The final command will be:

```
find . -name \*.pdf -print -exec pdfinfo {} \; | grep -E '^(\.|Pages)'
```

(redirect the output on your own).

Consider `-type f` as the first test in case some non-regular [file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690) matches `-name \*.pdf` by chance. This will avoid calling `pdfinfo` on directories and such.