# How to copy hidden file names to a text file in unix?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh

I have several directories which contain hidden empty files. I need the name of these file names themselves, so I need to write the filenames  to a txt file.
My script looks like this:

```
cd /z/all_vendors/
x=`find vendors -perm 755`
for FILE  in $x; do
    ls -a $FILE >> locator.txt
done
```

However I get a `permission denied error`
How do I write these hidden file names to a directory?

EDITS the vendors directory has subdirectories in the following way

```
vendors/
  |__000123
  |__000204
  |__000404
```

so `` x=`find vendors -perm 755` `` finds all subdirectories with certain permissions

Each of the `000xxx` subdirectories have the following tree structure:

```
000xxx/
  .
  ..
  .kpypjn32rz6l
  .66jwvo6x96sj
```

etc where the hidden files start with a dot

I need to write the names of the hidden files to a txt file for example 'kpypjn32rz6l'

Comment: (1) [Bash pitfall number 1](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29). (2) [Quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). (3) "Hidden" meaning "with names starting with a dot"? I'm asking because your code does not try to isolate such files (maybe because there are no non-hidden files?). (4) What does "the name of these file names themselves" mean? "Name of names"… what?

Comment: hidden meaning they start with a dot, the name of the files represent location codes

Comment: `cd /z/all_vendors/ && find vendors -name '.*' >> locator.txt`? This is not an answer because although I think the command kinda matches the (not entirely clear) description, I'm not sure if this is what you want, because your code may run `ls -a` for directories and non-directories. Is `-perm 755` your way to find directories maybe? Sorry, there is so much weirdness in the code, I am confused about your desired output. Maybe if you posted an example directory tree (from the command `tree`, [edit] the question) and the desired output, we could fix your code so it generates the output you want.

Comment: Also: what does "copy these hidden file names to a directory" mean? One can copy files (not names) to a directory. Your code writes some names to a file that is (hopefully) not a directory. IMO "copy names to directory" makes no sense.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: OK, now we're getting somewhere. (5) How important is `-perm 755`? Do you want to skip directories with other permissions? Or is this your (peculiar) way to pick all directories to iterate over them later? (6) The name of `.kpypjn32rz6l` is `.kpypjn32rz6l` but you specified `kpypjn32rz6l`. Please confirm you want to remove the dot from the output. // I'm asking because `cd /z/all_vendors/ && find vendors -type f -name '.*' -exec basename -a -- {} + >> locator.txt` is quite straightforward and I have my doubts regarding if you really need to complicate it. Is `basename -a` available in your OS?

Comment: Yes I need to skip other directories, I need to remove the dot from the output, and yes ```basename -a``` is available

Answer (score 0):

```sh
cd /z/all_vendors/ \
&& find vendors \
   \( -type d ! -path vendors ! -perm 755 -prune \) -o \
   \( -type f -name '.*' -exec basename -a -- {} + \) \
| sed 's/^\.//' >> locator.txt
```

Notes:

- If `cd` fails then `find` will not be executed. This is good practice.
- Any directory that doesn't match `-perm 755` will be pruned (i.e. `find` will not descend into it), regardless of its depth. It could be wrong e.g. if you wanted to descend many levels regardless of permissions and only check permissions of the bottom-level directory. I understand your directory structure is quite flat, so this shouldn't be a problem. With `! -path vendors` I ensure `vendors` will not be pruned, regardless of its permissions. (Note this is very sensitive to the path you supply to `find` as the starting point. `find vendors/ …` requires `! -path vendors/`; `find ./vendors …` requires `! -path ./vendors` etc.)
- I assumed by "file" you mean "regular file", therefore `-type f`. Formally "file" is a [broad term](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690).
- `basename` is a portable tool but its `-a` option is not portable. If your `basename` does not support `-a` then replace `-exec basename -a -- {} +` with `-exec basename -- {} \;`.
- Hopefully the filenames to be printed don't contain any newline characters. Newlines will terminate names. The standard approach in case filenames may contain newlines is terminating with null characters. Terminating with null characters would complicate our solution and make `locator.txt` not a text file ([POSIX definition of text file](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403) explicitly states it does not contain null characters).
- `sed` removes one leading dot per line.
- Files with identical names from different directories, if they match, will result in identical lines of output. Pipe to `sort -u` if you want to remove duplicate lines.