# List/Print oldest and newest file in each directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script, bash-scripting

Could use a bit of help guys.

I need to produce a report for the oldest and newest files that are residing in each unix directory

The structure is simple

Main folder with multiple subfolders that contains multiple files in each subfolder.

```
Folder
-Subfolders
--files
```

The below should output to txt file with following formatting.

```
SUBFOLDER_X
 OLDEST:Date:filename
 NEWEST:Date:filename
SUBFOLDER_Y
 OLDEST:Date:filename
 NEWEST:Date:filename
```

and so on...

I played with the below but stuck on getting it into shape of a report.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | cut -c3- |xargs ls -t | head -1
```

Any Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: (1) No sub-sub-…-directories. Please confirm. (2) Define "oldest"/"newest". You tried `ls -t`, so probably mtime matters for you. Please confirm. It could be btime. (3) Is your `find` the GNU `find`?

Comment: (1) No sub-sub. (2) Last modified so mtime. (3) Linux `find` . Been using  `ls -tr` and `ls -t` to get correct output. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `find -maxdepth 1`. I assume this is GNU `find` and other tools in your OS also support GNU extensions. **This answer uses GNU `find`, GNU `sort` and GNU `sed`; it is *not* portable.**

The following code is designed to handle all filenames (including filenames with newlines) reliably. Data is processed as null-terminated strings until finally `tr` converts nulls to newlines, so the output looks good¹ in a terminal. After the conversion the output may be ambiguous (because of newlines in filenames), but before the conversion it's not: each null-terminated line either begins with `./` (and then you know it's your `SUBFOLDER_*` line) or with  `OLDEST:`/ `NEWEST:`. If you want to parse the output further, do it before `tr` and keep in mind you're dealing with null-terminated lines.

`cd Folder` and then:

```
#!/bin/sh

for d in ./*/; do
( cd "$d" && {
  printf '%s\0' "$d"
  find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@ %TF:%P\0' \
  | sort -zn | sed -z '1 p' | sed -zn '
    1 {s/[^ ]* / OLDEST:/;p}
    $ {s/[^ ]* / NEWEST:/;p}
  '; }
)
done | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Notes:

- The shebang `#!/bin/sh` is to indicate the shell code is portable. I mean the shell code alone, the tools do use non-portable extensions. You don't need to run the code as a script, you don't need to run it strictly in `sh`, you can paste it into an interactive POSIX-compliant shell (e.g. Bash).
- We use a subshell (`( )`), so the scope of `cd` is limited.
- The trailing `/` in `for d in ./*/` means we're iterating over directories (and symlinks to directories).
- Remember `*` does not match names starting with a dot. Our code ignores hidden directories. Before you use `.*` (in case you want hidden directories), note it will match `.` and `..`.
- `./` in `for d in ./*/` is good for two reasons:

  1. We don't need [`--`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/108618) later in `cd "$d"` (more info: [*Filenames with leading dashes*](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#Filenames_with_leading_dashes)).
  2. If a subdirectory is named  `OLDEST:…`, it will appear as `./ OLDEST:…` and you will be able to tell it's a `SUBFOLDER_*` line. Without `./` the line may look like a genuine  `OLDEST:` line, unless you introduce an unambiguous prefix (e.g. `printf 'DIR:%s\0' "$d"`).
- In `find` I used `-type f` because you used it. I read the phrase "oldest and newest file" (in the title) according to the POSIX meaning of "file" [which is broad](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690). It seems you want regular files only.
- Note our loop over subdirectories includes symlinks to directories, but `-type f` does not match symlinks to regular files. And while `./*/` ignores hidden directories, `find` does not ignore hidden files.
- In `find` I used `-maxdepth 1` because you used it. Along with `-type f` this means sub-subdirectories (if any) and their content will be totally ignored as if they didn't exist.
- [Adjust `%TF`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Time-Formats.html) to your needs.
- A directory with no regular files will appear as a `./…` line with no  `OLDEST:`/ `NEWEST:` lines below.
- A directory with exactly one regular file will appear with the file listed both as  `OLDEST:` and  `NEWEST:`. For this case to work we needed to duplicate the first line from `find`, this is what `sed -z '1 p'` does (and if there are more lines then this `sed` will ultimately not matter).

---

¹ The output is not sanitized though. Your terminal may still intercept and react to [escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), bell characters or anything it's configured to react to, if such sequences or characters appear in filenames. To view the output safely, pipe it to a pager like `less`.

Comment: Works perfectly! Many thanks for taking time and doing the full explanation of the code. Super helpful for the beginners like me...

Comment: The Portion on line 5:
printf '%s\0' "$d"
What is that \0 doing specifically, I cannot find any information in man/google on what that does, and in testing, it seems to be identical to \n?

Comment: @DangerLake `\0` as a part of a format makes `printf` (or GNU `find -printf`) print a null byte. Data is processed as null-terminated lines, so if there is a newline character in any filename then it won't confuse `sort` or `sed` (and these tools are explicitly instructed to work with null-terminated lines: `-z`). Finally `tr` converts nulls to newlines. If we worked with `\n` then the tools wouldn't be able to tell apart genuine terminators from possible newlines in filenames. Thanks to `\0` his ambiguity appears in my answer only after `tr`, internally the code is robust.