# How to understand the hardlinks field of a directory

Tags: linux, filesystems, ls

I've run `ls -l` command but I have got a big confusion:

Ouput of ls -l in home directory:

```bash
$ ls -l
total 16
drwxr-x--- 19 farah   farah   4096 اگست   18 18:40 farah
drwxr-x--- 40 hussain hussain 4096 اگست   27 08:36 hussain
drwxr-x--- 19 remedy  remedy  4096 اگست   16 21:22 remedy
drwxr-x--- 19 saweiz  saweiz  4096 اگست    7 13:59 saweiz
```

why is it showing `total 16`
while only they are 4 directories in the `home` directory.

Ouput of `ls -la`

```bash
$ ls -la
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  6 root    root    4096 اگست    7 13:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root    root    4096 اگست   20 09:12 ..
drwxr-x--- 19 farah   farah   4096 اگست   18 18:40 farah
drwxr-x--- 40 hussain hussain 4096 اگست   27 08:36 hussain
drwxr-x--- 19 remedy  remedy  4096 اگست   16 21:22 remedy
drwxr-x--- 19 saweiz  saweiz  4096 اگست    7 13:59 saweiz
```

I don't know if it is something related to the OS but I am using Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original title is "How to understand the hardlinks field of a directory", but in the body you're asking about `total 16` which (as we will see) is not "the hardlinks field". The title is a misunderstanding.

The [POSIX specification of `ls`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html#tag_20_73_10) states that:

> If any of the `-l`, `-n`, `-s`, […] options is specified, each list of files within the directory shall be preceded by a status line indicating the number of file system blocks occupied by files in the directory in 512-byte units if the `-k` option is not specified, or 1024-byte units if the `-k` option is specified, rounded up to the next integral number of units, if necessary. In the POSIX locale, the format shall be:
>
> ```
> "total %u\n", <number of units in the directory>
> ```

**But** in Ubuntu your `ls` is GNU `ls` that [deviates from POSIX](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/What-information-is-listed.html#index-_002dl-6) [emphasis mine]:

> For each directory that is listed, preface the files with a line `total blocks`, where blocks is the file system allocation for all files in that directory. **The block size currently defaults to 1024 bytes**, but this can be overridden […].

In your cases each listed file was a directory that reported 4096 as its size (note it's the size of the respective directory as a [file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690), not the total size of files inside). This means each listed directory takes exactly four 1024-byte blocks. In the first case there were four of them on the list, hence 4x4= `total 16`; in the second case there were six, so 6x4= `total 24`.

You can make GNU `ls` obey the POSIX specification by setting the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable. AFAIK the value does not matter, it may even be empty, it's the existence of the variable that counts. Examples:

```
POSIXLY_CORRECT= ls -l
POSIXLY_CORRECT=whatever ls -la
```

In the directory in question these commands should print `total 32` and `total 48` respectively.

If anything can be called "the hardlinks field", it's what POSIX calls "number of links". In your examples it's [`19` for `farah`, `40` for `hussain`, `6` for `.` etc.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/43046/108618)

Comment: @MuhammadHussain "Sorry for not telling it but the question also included the field after the permissions field" – The original question certainly *did not*. You explicitly asked about `total 16` and I did my best to explain it. It's not elegant to substantially change the question after you got an answer. IMO the best would be to roll the question back to its original form and if you want explanation about "the field after the permissions field" then it should be a separate question. These things are distinct and deserve distinct answers.